# How to write an indicator function for this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I had just recently asked about sequences, and was told about indicator functions. I had asked about $$S= 1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0...$$
And concluded it was just 1 if the ordinal is a triangular number, and 0 elsewhere.

But what happens if the 1 changes with $n$, that is, the sequence
$$S=1,0,2,0,0,3,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,5...$$
How could you write that using an indicator function?

I've tried coming up with a few, but it always comes up a bit off.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the previous question was:
$$
f(n) = \begin{cases}
\color{red}1 \quad \text{$\exists k \in \mathbb N , n = \frac{k(k+1)}2 $} \\
0 \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Now, you would just write:
$$
f(n) = \begin{cases}
\color{blue}{k} \quad \text{$\exists k \in \mathbb N , n = \frac{k(k+1)}2 $} \\
0 \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Well, I feel silly now.
I had kept trying it by writing an $n$ where your $k$ is.

Comment: @RyanGoulden Don't worry, it has happened to all of us before. If you have realized your mistake, I am extremely happy. Now try more examples: For example, try the following: $1,1,2,1,1,3,1,1,1,4,1,1,1,1,5,1,1, \ldots$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Let $e_i$ denote the sequence which one in position $i$ and zero elsewhere.

Then your first $S$ is given by $$S=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}e_{\frac{i(i+1)}{2}}. $$

The second $S$ is given by $$S=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}ie_{\frac{i(i+1)}{2}}.$$

Comment: The first $S$ is given by a sum? How does this make any sense? $S$ is a **sequence**

Comment: @5xum: Because $e_i$ is a sequence, the sum of sequences is a sequence. Did you downvote for that? It's not wrong.

Comment: I was wrong. Sorry. I didn't see that $e_k$ is a sequence.

Comment: No problem, the subindex isn't nicely spaced so it's perhaps a bit unclear at first sight.